# Grails: params object empty

Tags: grails

in one of our projects the params object is always empty in gsp. When I want to have access to  params in a gap I do it like that:

```
${params.controller}
```

We use it in a if-clause:

```
<g:if test="${params.controller == 'import' && params.action == 'showTable'}">
```

It has worked fine but suddenly it stopped.

**EDIT: It is confusing that if I reload the page params are available!**

We do not have any filters and everything else works fine. Do you know if there is a configuration param? I could not find any helpful information about that and in case it is a project for our University we have some absolute beginners that may have changed something we have overseen in our git review.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything like params.controller = "whatever" instead of params.controller=="whatever". That happens sometimes.

Comment: @FranGarcía I did but have not found any wrong equals.

Comment: Just print params in the GSP to make sure that's empty.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I did and got the result that they are completely empty.

Comment: Try to isolate the gsp as much as possible, even moving this gsp as /index.gsp. Are you sure you don't have any filter or interceptor? Any plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails don't have the controller and action inside `params` by default, but the variables are accessible in the GSP.

Taken from [Grails Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/grails-goodness-access-action-and.html):

```
<%-- File: grails-app/views/view/index.gsp --%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GSP Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Action and Controller Name</h1>

        <ul>
            <li>controllerName: <strong>${controllerName}</strong></li>
            <li>actionName: <strong>${actionName}</strong></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```